# **Script does not work by his own on crontab and manually the script works fine**

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

**Script does not work by his own on crontab and manually the script works fine**

I have an issue with a script that i want to execute automatically, but doesn't work at reading a file (FILE_TEMP).

The file has all the permissions, even I had done other similar activities but in this case doesnt work by `cron`

with

> > crontab -e
>
> - - - - - /bin/bash /home/ops/OperatividadSemanal.sh

the script is:

> OperatividadSemanal.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data "{\"text\":\" Inicio \"}" https://hooks.slack.com

FILE="/home/ops/LastCheckOperatividadSemanal.csv"
wcl=$(cat $FILE| wc -l); hl=$(head $FILE)

FILE_TEMP="/home/ops/tempLastCheckOperatividadSemanal.csv"    
cat Prueba.csv > $FILE_TEMP; 
headTEMP=$(head $FILE_TEMP)
wclTEMP=$(cat $FILE_TEMP | wc -l)


curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data "{\"text\":\" FILE(wc -l=$wcl )\n head=$hl \n TEMP(wc -l= $wclTEMP ) \n $headTEMP \n \"}" https://hooks.slack.com

if [ $wclTEMP -ne 0 ]; then #man test -> INTEGER1 -ne INTEGER2 - INTEGER1 is not equal to INTEGER2
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data "{\"text\":\" \n if(wc -l from TEMP= $wclTEMP  ) \"}" https://hooks.slack.com
fi
```

And  it sends me a notification by slack(meessageApp) of the begining of the script and works fine showing me the FILE data but the FILE_TEMP shows me a word count(wc -l) of zero, even that i checked it and has like 400 lines.

`#man wc - (print newline, word, and byte counts for each file) -l, --lines`

The problem here is that the lecture of the FILE_TEMP doesn't works, and then it doesn't enter to the conditional if.

But if I execute it manual works fine.

The message i received by SLACK shows me data from FILE and doesnt show me info from FILE_TEMP.

Comment: Look up how to "redirect cron output." Cron jobs don't fail silently -- you need to redirect the output to a logfile so you can read the error message(s).

Comment: Where is `Prueba.csv` located? are you sure that `cat Prueba.csv > $FILE_TEMP` is not simply truncating `$FILE_TEMP`?

Comment: Prueba.csv is in the same place as the script. With your question i doubted and verify it. But its fine. @steeldriver

Comment: I don't know how to redirect the output from the output i will look up. It's a good idea for troubleshooting @user535733

Comment: `cron` doesn't care about the location of the script (since you've used its full path) - `Prueba.csv` won't be found unless it's in the cron  *working directory*

Comment: well i had specified the whole location of Prueba.csv (cat /home/ops/Prueba.scv) and doesn't work neither

Comment: seems you are missing a ```=``` in ```headTEMP$(head $FILE_TEMP)```

Comment: Please paste your script there first: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: the issue was that the file Prueba.csv did not have the whole direcction, thanks everybody :)

by specifying..... /home/ops/Prueba.csv works in cron